# Rails find_by returns nil, but record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

If I do `Model.find_by_column(column_data)`, the return is `Nil`, but when I copy the generated SQL to `rails db` console (postgresql db shell), the record shows up.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Example code:

```
garden = Garden.find_by_name("Zen Garden")
puts garden.inspect
```

Returns:

```
SELECT  "gardens".* FROM "gardens"  WHERE "gardens"."name" = 'Zen Garden' LIMIT 1
Nil
```

But in database:

```
SELECT  "gardens".* FROM "gardens"  WHERE "gardens"."name" = 'Zen Garden' LIMIT 1;
 id |    name    |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 82 | Zen Garden | 2014-10-23 03:56:25.614274 | 2014-10-23 03:56:25.614274
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: I assume you were running Garden.find_by in rails console? The reason I ask is because I'm wondering if the environment is the same in both contexts.. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Just to discard this option, try this: Garden.where('name LIKE ?', '%Zen Garden%'). Maybe there's a space at the end or beginning of name. What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was copy-pasting `create()` line AND I also accidentally accepted `update_all` instead of `update_attributes` in CodeIntel.